# Comparing 2 Cluster solutions using k-means clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am experimenting with clustering in R for the first time and have been looking at the basic R help online and tried to compare the outcome of 2 cluster solutions.

I copied and pasted the script being careful to make sure that I had named the relevant data sets correctly first, but keep getting an error message that i don't understand.

Any ideas?

The script is simply:

## comparing 2 cluster solutions

```
library(fpc)
cluster.stats (d, fit1$cluster, fit2$cluster)
```

and the error message I am getting is:

```
> library(fpc)
> cluster.stats(d, fit1$cluster, fit2$cluster)
Error in as.matrix.dist(d) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as.dist.default(d) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as.dist.default(d) : non-square matrix
3: In as.matrix.dist(d) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the `d` object should contain a matrix of distances (usually symetrical matrix with zeroes on diagonal). in R can obtain the distance matrix using

```
d <- dist(clustering_result)
```